# Difference between C and C++ Building Process

Tags: c++, c, compilation, linker, c-preprocessor

From what I understand, the C language consists of a 4 stage compilation process:

On my Windows OS -

1. Preprocessor
2. Assembling
3. Compilation
4. Linking

I want to know if there are any differences between a C compiler and C++ compiler, in terms of the steps above. I believe that C++ can also consist of the above 4 stages.

Are there any differences that I am not aware of from a big picture perspective?

Comment: You should switch step `b` and `c`. Also, most compilers today doesn't generate assembler unless asked to, instead they generate object code directly. And yes, C++ compilers follows the same steps.

Comment: Edited and voted to re-open. Hopefully you will get the answers you need.

Comment: @0A0D: Thanks for reopening the Question.In future I will keep in mind the format for acceptable questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The preprocessing and linking stages are basically the same (C and C++ share the preprocessor, and linking is done with no regard for the source language). The compilation/assembling phase is still there, but it has to be different - after all, we are dealing with a difference language here.

Edit: the details of C vs. C++ compilation are far too much to answer here ;)

Comment: If I remember correctly, C++ does require some linker support due to templates and inline functions. Namely, so it doesn't complain about duplicate symbols.

Comment: The linker works the same. It is the code emitting phase which marks template-derived symbols as "weak", allowing them to be linked properly. Notice that you can use the same linker and the same object file format for both!

Comment: I want to know between pre-processor and compilation assembler stage performs what function.

Comment: @PrasoonMishra : the assembly stage (if it is separate from compilation) turns compiler-generated assembly language code into machine-readable binary form appropriate for the target CPU

Comment: @ Grzegorz Herman :But assembly phase is finished before compilation.

Comment: @PrasoonMishra : no, it is not, unless it is a part of it

Comment: @GrzegorzHerman: A pure C linker wouldn't need to support "weak" symbols and inline (i.e. multiply-defined) functions. You can only use the same linker for both if it supports the extra requirements of C++.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: true, I guess I never had to work with a linker old-enough _not_ to support what C++ needs :)

Comment: @MikeSeymour: That's true for C89, I know, but is it still the case with C99? It's got rather complex `inline` rules.

Comment: @MSalters: Good question; I haven't done much C in the last decade or so, so I never got round to learning the details of C99.